# How do I keep the buffer list open for 1 more command?

Tags: buffers

Is there a way to keep the buffer list open so I can select a buffer?

I.e., I do `ls`, then the buffer list shows up with the 'enter a command or press enter' prompt - I would like to press, for example, :5 *but have the buffer list stay visible for this single command*.

I'm pretty sure I've had this working before but I deleted my config X(

Comment: As in `:ls<ENTER>` then press colon `:` ... ? The "*enter a command*" is for example `:b5`

Comment: @Moba correct, I want to be able to still see the buffer list when typing b5

Comment: @Moba is saying this should work by default. At the `:help hit-enter` prompt, you can immediately type `:`

Comment: @Ben I'm using Windows 10 and as soon as I hit ``:`` I lose the list of buffer built by ``:ls``.

Comment: I'm currently using the [wilder.nvim](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim) plugin. With the plugin the :b command build the list of existing buffer as a floating window on top of the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly your question, this is a very popular request and not surprisingly, there is an equally popular mapping for it:

```
nnoremap <Leader>b :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

(this assumes you already set `mapleader`, but you can change it if you want)

I have set `<Leader>` to `\<space>`, so when I press `Space + b`, the output of `:ls` is shown in addition to the command `:b`  ready for you to type the number for the desired buffer and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use the wildmenu:

`:set wildmenu`

If set when using the `:b`  (notice the trailing space) command you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to ask for a list of possible completions which is somehow the full list of open buffers is you enter only one space as hit.

If you like to have the list of possible completion vertical I recommend you to install the [wilder.nvm](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim) plugin.

[image]